# Which certificates does the IIS https binding 'SSL certificate' dropdown show?

Tags: binding, ssl-certificate, iis-10

It seems to only show certificates that are in the LocalMachine\Personal store?

Comment: That's the most common place people install server certificates. However, IIS Manager can also show certificates installed in LocalMachine\WebHosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two place to install certificates: local computer and current user.

IIS also can show certificates that are in local computer.
[image]

Comment: So certificates that are say in LocalMachine\Trusted Root CA or Intermediate CA can’t appear in that dropdown?

Comment: Yes. Most of them are root certificates, and root certificates can issue more certificates. Trusting the root certificate will automatically trust the certificate issued by the root certificate, instead of manually adding each certificate to the machine's trusted certificate. Generally, we do not use the root certificate but the certificate issued by the root certificate in the browser. Therefore, the root certificate is not displayed in IIS. Unless you create a self-signed root certificate yourself.